# How do I assign a value calculated at runtime in a function to a form control?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a value that is generated and assigned to a integer variable in a private function in a form, but I can not seem to assign it to a form control ( a text box ) in the form.

I have tcount defined in the **General area** of the form (to make it accessible outside the function where i am trying to assign the returned value).  I am assigning the result of another function call to tcount like this.

```
tcount = CountValues(Me.RecordSource,"[columnname]")
```

I am using a MsgBox to output tcount and it looks good.

I have tried assigning tcount a couple ways to the text area.

```
Set frmname.controlname = tcount   'error - you entered an expression that has no value'
Set Me.controlname = tcount        'error - you entered an expression that has no value'
frmname.controlname = tcount       'run-time error 2448, cant assign a value to this object'
Set Form.subfrmname.controlname = tcount   'Application-defined or object-defined error'
```

Thank you for insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is used when assigning to an object variable, not when assigning to simple data type variables.  In this case the assignment is to a text box value property, so treat it the same as assigning a value to a variable.

Use either of the following to store the integer in your text box.

```vb
Me.controlname = tcount
Me.controlname.Value = tcount
```

Comment: When I try Me.controlname = tcount, I get run time error '-2147352567  can't assign a value to this object....with Me.controlname.Value = tcount, I get run time error 2448, can't assign a value to this object.... i will keep trying

Comment: If `Me.controlname` is really a text box, I don't understand why you get that error.  When you get the error, click the button to go into break (debug) mode and see what you get from this in the Immediate window: `? Typename(Me.controlname)`

Comment: Great call, I had hard coded a value in the control source.....that was causing the error.  Once I removed, working like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: I encountered this issue also and after an hour of messing around it turned out it was because I'd set a ControlSource on the control.